# NullReferenceException when a value is entered

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, nullreferenceexception

Here's my entire code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void sldChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        double red, green, blue;
        red = sldRed.Value;
        green = sldGreen.Value;
        blue = sldBlue.Value;
        changeColors(red, green, blue);
    }

    private void inputChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double red, green, blue;
        red = Convert.ToDouble(txtRed.Text);
        green = Convert.ToDouble(txtGreen.Text);
        blue = Convert.ToDouble(txtBlue.Text);
        sldRed.Value = red;
        sldGreen.Value = green;
        sldBlue.Value = blue;
        changeColors(red, green, blue);
    }

    void changeColors(double red, double green, double blue)
    {

    }

    private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtRed.Text = Convert.ToString(sldRed.Value);
        txtGreen.Text = Convert.ToString(sldGreen.Value);
        txtBlue.Text = Convert.ToString(sldBlue.Value);
    }
}
```

and here's my entire .xaml code.

```
<Grid x:Name="frmGrid" Margin="0,0,2,0">
    <Slider x:Name="sldRed" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="57,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="757" ValueChanged="sldChanged" ClipToBounds="True" Maximum="255" TickPlacement="BottomRight" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" SmallChange="1" Value="1"/>
    <Slider x:Name="sldBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="57,76,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="757" ValueChanged="sldChanged" ClipToBounds="True" Maximum="255" TickPlacement="BottomRight" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" SmallChange="1" Value="1"/>
    <Slider x:Name="sldGreen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="57,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="757" ValueChanged="sldChanged" ClipToBounds="True" Maximum="255" TickPlacement="BottomRight" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" SmallChange="1" Value="1"/>
    <Label Content="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label Content="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label Content="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtRed" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="819,9,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="41" TextChanged="inputChanged"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="819,74,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="41" TextChanged="inputChanged"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtGreen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="819,41,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="41" TextChanged="inputChanged" Text="1"/>

</Grid>
```

You can see I've assigned a value to those textboxes for testing purposes.

For some reason I keep getting this error
[image]

Which refers to these two lines.

```
green = Convert.ToDouble(txtGreen.Text);
blue = Convert.ToDouble(txtBlue.Text);
```

Note how the similar line above it works perfectly

```
red = Convert.ToDouble(txtRed.Text);
```

I'm not that experienced in C# yet, nor am I experienced in reading errors like those.
If you have any idea as to why I'm getting this error and maybe provide me with a possible solution, it would be greatly appreciated.

PS: Something I just thought might be of use to you, I get this error before the program even starts up.

Here's 2 screenshots where 1 doesn't load at all, while the 2nd loads perfectly & works.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you run it in debug mode to make sure they are truly non-null?

Comment: I don't think it's on any of those lines. What happens when you let it continue?

Comment: Click Break and get the Exception details from the debugger. Post them here.

Comment: You should use `Double.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToDouble`

Comment: @HenkHolterman when I let it continue the entire program just stops. Where exactly can I find those Exception details? Are those the lines in the Call Stack window? (It's the only window I can find that contains error-like stuff. The error list is completely empty.

Comment: When the program fails what are the values of the `Text` property on your TextBox.  Unless your willing to debug this some more on your own we can't help.  Replace the code with a static string that isn't from the `Text` property and go from there.  Why do you have a method called `inputChanged` when a method with a very similar name already exists for TextBoxes?

Comment: is it possible that you are setting the value of the text in the text boxes manually via code somewhere else in your code?

Comment: @Ramhound I've got a new method because all 3 textboxes I have use the same method, instead of having to make a seperate method for each textbox.

Comment: @AlexGelman In the window_loaded method, I get the value from my sliders (default value 1). But when I comment out those lines it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Yorrick - You do understand that when the value of `Text` changes to a null string your event happens right?

Comment: could you post your entire code? or perhaps the stack trace of the exception

Answer (score 2):

`txtRed and txtBlue` does not contain value. but txtRed contains value

You can add validation script in order to ensure that yours controls are not empty

Comment: he has set a value for all text boxes in the xaml

Comment: how tu know ? @Alex i'am curious

Comment: @AlexGelman - He might think he is but clearly based on the error he isn't.

Comment: @HenkHolterman hitting backspace will set the text to be an empty string, not a null value.

Comment: @Yorrick - You need to use the debugger and update the question to indicate what the values of the `Text` property is at the time of the `inputChanged` event.  You can use the Watcher to do this, post the results, this will be able determine the cause on your own if you do this.

Answer (score 0):

The event handler fires when the input changes. If you hit backspace in any one of the boxes your Text is now an empty string or null. You can't turn those into doubles. Try Double.TryParse() instead of Convert.ToDouble() to determine if it's actually a parsable input like so:

```
private void inputChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    double red, green, blue;

    if(Double.TryParse(txtRed.Text, out red) &&
        Double.TryParse(txtGreen.Text, out green) &&
        Double.TryParse(txtBlue.Text, out blue)) 
    {
        sldRed.Value = red;
        sldGreen.Value = green;
        sldBlue.Value = blue;
        changeColors(red, green, blue);
    }
}
```

If all the values in the RGB TextBoxes are valid the if statement will be true and red, green and blue will be set properly.

This is of course assuming that sldGreen and sldBlue are not null.

Comment: How can I hit backspace when the form I'm trying to load isn't loading at all?

Comment: Then that is not the method the error is coming from. There is an error somewhere else in your code. Do you know how to use the debugger in VS?

Comment: @Yorrick - That isn't possible.  If `Double.TryParse` fails the value of the `out` value is `0`.  This means the exception is not cause by the code you posted.

Comment: ... I know for a fact it's this method the error is coming from because when I comment out the lines which convert my green & blue textboxes, the program works fine, then.

Comment: Are you certain sldGreen and sldBlue are not null? if they are the Value property would throw the NullReferenceException.

Comment: @AndrewMartin if you read my xaml code properly, you'll see i've given all 3 sliders the same value, being "1" in it's properties.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your `Window_Loaded_1` it changes the text value of the text boxes causing the `inputChanged` method to be called. try commenting out the code in `Window_Loaded_1` and see if the exception still happens.

One way to solve this problem is to use binding to wire together the values of the sliders and the text boxes.
Your xaml should look like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="frmGrid" Margin="0,0,2,0">
    <Slider x:Name="sldRed" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="57,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="757" ValueChanged="sldChanged" ClipToBounds="True" Maximum="255" TickPlacement="BottomRight" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" SmallChange="1" Value="1"/>
    <Slider x:Name="sldBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="57,76,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="757" ValueChanged="sldChanged" ClipToBounds="True" Maximum="255" TickPlacement="BottomRight" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" SmallChange="1" Value="1"/>
    <Slider x:Name="sldGreen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="57,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="757" ValueChanged="sldChanged" ClipToBounds="True" Maximum="255" TickPlacement="BottomRight" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" SmallChange="1" Value="1"/>
    <Label Content="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label Content="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label Content="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    <TextBox x:Name="txtRed" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="819,9,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ElementName=sldRed, Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="41"/>

    <TextBox x:Name="txtBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="819,74,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ElementName=sldBlue, Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="41"/>

    <TextBox x:Name="txtGreen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="819,41,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="41" Text="{Binding ElementName=sldGreen, Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}"/>


</Grid>
```

and your code should look like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void sldChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        red = sldRed.Value;
        green = sldGreen.Value;
        blue = sldBlue.Value;
        changeColors(red, green, blue);
    }

    void changeColors(double red, double green, double blue)
    {

    }
}
```

You can get rid of `inputChanged` and respond only to the slider changes

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is failing is because the valuechanged event gets called when you initially create the slider in xaml and include this: Value="1".  The event gets raised before the other controls are created, and thus the null exception.

WPF is built heavily upon the concept of binding, and you should utilize it as much as possible because it will make your life a lot easier.  I altered your code to show you how to do it using bindings.

xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        x:Name="TheMainWindow">
    <Grid x:Name="frmGrid" Margin="0,0,2,0">
        <Slider x:Name="sldRed" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="57,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="757" ClipToBounds="True" Maximum="255" TickPlacement="BottomRight" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" 
                SmallChange="1" Value="{Binding Path=Red, ElementName=TheMainWindow, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Slider x:Name="sldBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="57,76,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="757" ClipToBounds="True" Maximum="255" TickPlacement="BottomRight" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" 
                SmallChange="1" Value="{Binding Path=Blue, ElementName=TheMainWindow, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Slider x:Name="sldGreen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="57,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="757" ClipToBounds="True" Maximum="255" TickPlacement="BottomRight" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
                SmallChange="1" Value="{Binding Path=Green, ElementName=TheMainWindow, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Label Content="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label Content="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label Content="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtRed" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="819,9,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Red, ElementName=TheMainWindow}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="41"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="819,74,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Blue, ElementName=TheMainWindow}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="41" />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtGreen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="819,41,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Text="{Binding Path=Green, ElementName=TheMainWindow}" Width="41" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private double _red = 1;
    public double Red
    {
        get { return _red; }
        set
        {
            _red = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Red");
        }
    }

    private double _green = 1;
    public double Green
    {
        get { return _green; }
        set
        {
            _green = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Green");
        }
    }

    private double _blue = 1;
    public double Blue
    {
        get { return _blue; }
        set
        {
            _blue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Blue");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```